# Stanford NLP Parser Model Jar too large

Tags: stanford-nlp

I use maven for managing dependencies. I need to use the Stanford NLP Parser to get universal dependencies for english sentences. I'm using the edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz model. My pom.xml contains the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

By adding the models dependency, the jar size increases by around 300MB. I need to make sure that the jar is as small as possible. Is there any way to handle this in maven ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the jar smaller by not including the models, and referencing them from elsewhere (i.e., specify a custom path for the property `parse.model`), but in general if you'd like to produce parse trees, you need to have the parser model accessible *somewhere*. CoreNLP includes it in the model jar by default, to make it easier to run the code independent of your particular directory structure.

The other option is to run the CoreNLP Server, and then you only need the client library (the server includes the models jar).